# Loop over columns R

Tags: r, loops

I have a `data.frame` in `R` that consists in a number of columns with numerical values.
Like this:

```
   A       B      C
0.6057  0.1644  6.93
0.5723  0.117   6.59
0.5614  0.1552  7.02
0.4102  0.1059  5.24
0.4945  0.0857  6.64
0.5157  0.0747  7.06
0.7785  0.1394  5.21
0.5492  0.1557  6.06
0.5411  0.1884  5.68
0.6622  0.148   6.1
```

For each of these columns, I want to create a new column containing the quartile values. I have no problem doing it over one column at a time using this formula:

```
tableOne <- within(data, quartile <-
                    as.integer(cut(A, quantile(A, probs=0:5/5,na.rm=T))))
```

But as I have `100 columns` with different names, I wanted to loop over each column separately.

I tried a loop without success:

```
for(i in names(data)){
  tableOne <- within(data, quarti <- as.integer(cut(i, quantile(i, probs=0:5/5,na.rm=T))))
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in cut.default(i, quantile(i, probs = 0:5/5, na.rm = T)) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

I also tried apply function:

```
df.two <- lapply(df, function(x) within(data, quartile <- as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=0:5/5,na.rm=T)))))
```

with no success:

```
Error during wrapup: argument "obj" is missing, with no default
Error during wrapup: target context is not on the stack
```

Any advices on how to iterate my functions over all the columns and get all results in the same data.frame?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Create a function (with a vector as parameter) and use `lapply`.

Comment: I tried with apply but I am not better at it than the loop!

Comment: `df.two <- lapply(data, function(x) within(data, quartile <- as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=0:5/5,na.rm=T)))))`

Comment: Maybe, `cbind(df, lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=0:5/5,na.rm=T)))))`, but I can't test since you don't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Yeah sorry I did not want to bother everybody with a long dataset but unfortunatelly I can't make it work! So I am going to edit my post and add some dataset

Comment: You example dataset does not need more than 3 columns and maybe 10 rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See end of answer for a better approach, this one is for easy understanding of the steps.

I'm unsure what you're willing to do, but maybe this:

```
df2<- as.data.frame( lapply( df, function(x){
  as.integer( cut(x, quantile(x, probs=(0:5)/5, na.rm=T)))
}))
colnames(df2) <- paste0("quartile_",colnames(df))
df3 <- cbind(df,df2)
```

Which gives:

```
        A      B    C quartile_A quartile_B quartile_C
1  0.6057 0.1644 6.93          4          5          4
2  0.5723 0.1170 6.59          4          2          3
3  0.5614 0.1552 7.02          3          4          5
4  0.4102 0.1059 5.24         NA          2          1
5  0.4945 0.0857 6.64          1          1          4
6  0.5157 0.0747 7.06          2         NA          5
7  0.7785 0.1394 5.21          5          3         NA
8  0.5492 0.1557 6.06          3          4          2
9  0.5411 0.1884 5.68          2          5          2
10 0.6622 0.1480 6.10          5          3          3
```

Datas used:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(0.6057, 0.5723, 0.5614, 0.4102, 0.4945, 
0.5157, 0.7785, 0.5492, 0.5411, 0.6622), B = c(0.1644, 0.117, 
0.1552, 0.1059, 0.0857, 0.0747, 0.1394, 0.1557, 0.1884, 0.148
), C = c(6.93, 6.59, 7.02, 5.24, 6.64, 7.06, 5.21, 6.06, 5.68, 
6.1)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

---

As per @DavidArenburg comment below a better way to achieve the same result is:

```
df[paste0("quartile_",colnames(df))] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=(0:5)/5, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

This avoid creating a new dataframe and copying it over at end.

Comment: You could do this in one go using `df[paste0("quartile_",colnames(df))] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=(0:5)/5, na.rm = TRUE))))`

Comment: @David I kept it in 3 steps to ease the understanding (and been too lazy to shorten it on 1 pass), that said you should add it as another answer for future readers ;)

Comment: I think you could just edit... I dont see a reason to convert to `data.frame` again, create a new object and then copy everything again using `cbind`. The above line isn't just shorter but is much more efficient I would think.

Comment: @David and as it's yours, I don't wish to steal it ;) It's perfectly valid to have multiple answers, and here it's a different approach so it should stand on it's own to allow other to vote for the most useful/performant one to guide readers on their choose (In my humble opinion)