# For loop deleting "," in factor variables to make them numeric (R user)

Tags: r, for-loop, numeric

I try to delete all "," from a set of variables in my data frame (df). For a single variable (e.g. debt), I successfully run:

```
df$debt <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",df$debt))
```

And it exactly does what I want (i.e. overwrites the factor variable "1,324,234.35" into a numeric "1324234.35"). So, I create the following for loop with a variable list:

```
dflist <- c("debt","fundequity","age","coempl","corev")
for (i in dflist) {
  df$i <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",df$i))
}
```

but when I run it, R returns the following error:

```
> dflist <- c("debt","fundequity","age","coempl","corev")
> for (i in dflist) {
+   df$i <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",df$i))
+ }
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "i", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 570225
```

How can I make it work? Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: Although similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294346/loop-over-columns-r), the output error is different, plus I need to overwrite my variables. After the proposed solution (see below), it seemed the problem was in the $ sign.

Comment: you could also use `df[dflist] <- lapply(df[dflist], readr::parse_number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access each column with `df$i` with `i` being a variable.
You could use the `apply` family like such:

```
df[,dflist] = apply(df[,dflist],2,function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",","",x)))
```

If you want to stick to loops, you can use

```
for (i in dflist){
    df[,i]=as.numeric(gsub(",","",df[,i]))
}
```